# Pass a template method as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, argument-passing

Could some one help me how to implement this code?

I need to pass a function to another function:

```
std::cout << process_time(Model::method1) << std::endl;
```

This function gets the function as a template type and calls it on an object

```
template <typename F>
double process_time(F algorithm)
{
    Model model;
    double time=0;
    do
    {
        // ...
        time += model.algorithm(arg1);
    } while (! stop_criteria);
    return time;
}
```

Note that `method1` is a function template as well:

```
template <typename T>
double method1(std::vector<T> &v)
{
    ...
}
```

What is the legal syntax for it?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Model
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    double method1(std::vector<T> &v)
    {
        double t = 0;
        //...
        return t;
    }

    template <typename T>
    double method2(std::vector<T> &v)
    {
        double t = 0;
        //...
        return t;
    }

};

template <typename F>
double process_time(F algorithm)
{
    Model model;
    double time = 0;
    bool stop_criteria = false;
    do
    { 
        std::vector<int> arg1;
        // ...
        time += model.algorithm(arg1);
    } while (!stop_criteria);
    return time;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << process_time(Model::method1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `method1`? What're you trying to do? Can you provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is `process_time`?

Comment: @anxieux sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest to your code that compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Model {
  template <typename T>
  double method1(std::vector<T> &v) {
    double t = 0;
    //...
    return t;
  }
};

template <typename F>
double process_time(F algorithm) {
    Model model;
    double time = 0;
    bool stop_criteria = false;
    do
    { 
        std::vector<int> arg1;
        // ...
        time += (model.*algorithm)(arg1);
    } while (!stop_criteria);
    return time;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << process_time(&Model::method1<int>) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is that `method1` is a function *template*:

```
template <typename T> double method1(std::vector<T>& );
```

As such, it's not *a* function... it's a family of functions. `process_time` expects a single function, so you just have to pass it the *one* function that you want to use:

```
std::cout << process_time(method1<int>) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `process time` line with `time +=` to:

```
   time += algorithm(&model,arg1);
```

then call it with:

```
std::cout << process_time([](Model* m, std::vector<int>& v){return m->method1(v);}) << std::endl;
```

or in C++14:

```
std::cout << process_time([](Model* m, auto& v){return m->method1(v);}) << std::endl;
```

which leaves the choice of what kind of vector it will pass to `method1` up to `process_time` instead of fixing it at the calling site.

Basically, this avoids dealing with pointer-to-member variables.  Instead, the `algorithm` in `process_time` is just a map from `Model` x `vector` to `double`.  This also means that we can have a non-member `algorithm`.

If you don't like the verbosity of the above at the call site, you can keep the changes to `process_time` and change the call to:

```
std::cout << process_time(std::ref(&Model::method1<int>)) << std::endl;
```

as `std::ref` takes a pointer to a member function, and returns a callable object that takes a pointer-to-`Model` as the first argument, and `std::vector<int>&` as the second.  Which matches how we use it.